# Custom UITableViewCell height based on descendant view (xCode 6, iOS8)

Tags: uitableview, ios8, xcode6

I have a custom view inside a prototype cell, with a label and a UIImageView that can both be variable heights.  What is the best approach to get the table cells to adjust to the view's height?  It seems I have to set a height to the table cell and anything else I try won't reset the size.

i've tried the concept below with no luck.

```
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 260.0
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the height for `UITableViewCell` should be fixed. You could have more than 1 type of `UITableViewCell` inside the same `UITableView`. For example, the section 0 has a unique type of `UITableViewCell`, the `UITableViewCell` for the other sections have another type. Then inside the TableView Delegate method `heightForRowAtIndexPath`, you may set the height for the different types of `UITableViewCell`.

You could do something like this:-

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    if(indexPath.section==0)
        return 40;
    else
        return 60;
}
```